# javascript - how to clear content inside of `console.group`?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

I want to clear all of the content inside a `console.group` without clear another `console.group` content?

for example, I want to clear `a section` in the console without clearing the `b section` content?

```js
console.group('a');
console.log('a section');
console.groupEnd();

console.group('b');
console.log('b section');
console.groupEnd();
```

I tried clear the console with `console.clear()` but this function clear all of the page!

Is it possible at all?
It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Comment: I don't think it's possible yet. [Referring to this](https://console.spec.whatwg.org) there's no other way to clear the console other than .clear method (which takes no parameter) and it says, it will clear the console if the environment allows. Not sure, if there's any other way around it. It'd be interesting if some way exists. Gonna bookmark it